# Iterating through a multiple data frames

Tags: r

With two or more dataframes, `df1, df2, df3, df4, ...` what data structure should be used such that it is possible to iterate through the dataframes and do something with each.

```
for(df in 'what') {
  print(colnames(df))
}
```

The `what` part - which data structure to be used so that each dataframe can be accessed to do something with it in side the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better not to even create separate objects in the global environment.  Instead the files can be read directly into a `list`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")
lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
lst1 <- map(files, read_csv)
```

and then get the column names from the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(lst1, names)
```

---

Also, if the files are really big, an option is also with [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) which can condense all the files into a single data.frame

```
library(vroom)
files <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "csv")
out <- vroom::vroom(files)
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually, it is better to have data in a list instead of having separate dataframes in the global environment. Keeping data in list is easier to manage.

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df\\d+'))
```

and use `lapply` to *do something* on each one of it.

```
lapply(list_df, function(x) names(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
for(df in list(band_instruments, iris, mtcars)){

  print(colnames(df))
}

# [1] "name"  "plays"
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```